# Purge css returning only commented code instead of used css

Tags: php, css, frontend, css-purge

I am trying to use purgecss on windows however the code returns commented code when it should return css that is used

Can someone tell me why?How to fix?
The directory structure in the cmd command is correct

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\healinghandsclinic>purgecss --css css/custom.css --content 'index.php' 'js/*.js' --output C:\Users\soura\Desktop\ --config purgecss.config.js
```

I even added config file in root directory healinghandsclinic to check but it still doesn't work

purgecss.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    content: ['index.php', 'js/*.js'],
    css: ['css/custom.css'],
    whitelist: ['#HomeExperiencesWrapper'],
  };
```